# Managed property not returning results in search

Tags: 2013, search, managed-property, crawled-property

I created 2 managed properties that mapped 2-3 crawled properties each. The advance query works for one but not the other. I tried full crawl, clearing the config but not able to get it working.

Comment: Where is the Crawled property coming from? Where is the Managed Property defined?

Comment: I have set up a search center , the crawled properties are coming from a site collection. And managed property is defined in Central Admin

Comment: Is there data in the column? Do the data type and Managed Property types match?